# How to find shortest paths between two nodes based on certain edge attribute using igraph in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I have made a directed graph in Rstudio using igraph package. For each edge I have set an edge attribute called edge_ids. Multiple edges are there with the same edge_id. Now I want to find if there exists a path between 2 nodes with a particular edge_id?

So basically, suppose I have a graph of  trips covered by 10 vehicles  and each vehicle has its own vehicle_id. Now if I want to find the shortest distance between 2 nodes in this graph, then it will consider all 10 vehicles, but what I want is that it should consider only that vehicle whose vehicle_id will be given by me.

```
shortest.paths(total_network, 'ttn85jv', 'ttn9rjy')
E(total_network)[edge_id=="0358511023767613_132.csv"]
```

First line will give me shortest path between node ttn85jv and ttn9rjy.
Second line will give me edge sequence vector having edge id=0358511023767613_132.csv.

If edge id=0358511023767613_132.csv has created a path in the (total_network) graph, then I want to find if nodes ttn85jv and ttn9rjy are coming in between the path or not.

If both the nodes exist in the path, then what is the path length between these two nodes for that id(0358511023767613_132.csv)

I have got an answer for this. But it is not an optimal way, also it is taking very long time to execute because first it is making subgraph of the given graph(total_network).

```
s1 <- subgraph.edges(total_network, E(total_network)[edge_id=="0358511023767613_132.csv"])
shortest.paths(s1,'ttn9rjy','ttn85jv')
```

Comment: Is it `subgraph.edges()` or `shortest.paths()` that slows you down? You're not giving enough info about the size and structure of your data to suggest optimisations. How many nodes, what is the distribution (number of edges of each) edge_id:s and number of nodes?

Comment: number of nodes are around 20,000 and number of edges are 5 lakhs. Also, same edge_ids will represent a route in a network. There can be multiple edges between 2 nodes having different edge_ids(if multiple cars are running between 2 nodes then they will have different edge_ids).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already provide a functioning solution to your question, but Tthere *are* faster ways than `subgraph.edges()` for checking edges by edge-id.

Try, for example to define `n <- make_empty_graph(n = length(V(total_network)))` as an empty network and then find distances with this:

```
#s1 <- subgraph.edges(total_network, E(total_network)[edge_id=="0358511023767613_132.csv"])
s1 <- n %>% add_edges( as.vector(ends(total_network, E(total_network)[edge_id=="0358511023767613_132.csv"])) )
```

My version creates the subgraph much quicker. On my 2017 Mac, the speed advantages seem to be about 2x, but depend on network size. Maybe the advantages are different for you size of network?

[image]

Comment: s1 %>% add_edges( as.vector(ends(total_network, E(total_network) [edge_id=="0358511023767613_132.csv"])) )


By running this line I get edge sequence vector. Now I want to find the path length between any 2 nodes in this edge sequence. If both nodes are present in this edge sequence then it should give me the path length otherwise if any one node or both the nodes are not present then it should return that the path length is not possible.

Comment: Ah. I was too fast. The correct code-line for the faster sub-graphing should strart with `s1 <- n %>%`... I've edited the answer. The path-length you then check on the sub-graph which you created to isolate the `egde_id` of your choice: `shortest.paths(s1, 'ttn85jv', 'ttn9rjy')`